# How to separate each animation to each element in angular?

Tags: angular, animation

I am trying to use the same animation in angular for different elements, these elements should act separately on click

```
<div id="a" #a [@blast]="state" (click)="yell($event)"><div>
<div id="b" #b [@blast]="state" (click)="yell($event)"><div>
<div id="c" #c [@blast]="state" (click)="yell($event)"><div>

yell(event){
    let idAttr=event.srcElement.attributes.id
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue; //to get divs id
if(value==="a"){
//for element "a" only, animate with blast animation
}
if(value==="b"){
//for element "b" only, animate with blast animation
}
if(value==="b"){
//for element "b" only, animate with blast animation
}
}
```

What is the smartest option?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this may be the best option:

```
    <div id="a" #a [@blast]="a_status" (click)="yell($event)"><div>
    <div id="b" #b [@blast]="b_status" (click)="yell($event)"><div>
    <div id="c" #c [@blast]="c_status" (click)="yell($event)"><div>

a_status:string;
b_status:string;
c_status:string;


yell(event){
    let idAttr=event.srcElement.attributes.id
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue; //to get divs id
if(value==="a"){
this.a_status="fire"
}
if(value==="b"){
this.b_status="fire"
}
if(value==="b"){
this.c_status="fire"
}
}
```